# Rails: Sending email after sign up takes a while... What should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a landing page where I let visitors to enter their email so that whenever we launch we can let them know.  Right now, I am basically doing the following in my create action of my RegistrationsController.

```
UserSignUpMailer.welcome_email(resource).deliver
```

The problem here is that, since that deliver takes a while, the 'thank you' and other text that we show right after takes a while to show up.

I am wondering what are the possible solutions to this. I don't care if the email is sent right after 5 seconds or even 1 minute after, I prefer that the user doesn't wait for that text to show up.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Emails should be handled as background jobs.

Resque and Delayed Jobs are among the most popular.

Relevant Railscasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque

Comment: I'd also add sidekiq: http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq
Eats less RAM and looks more lightweight